# Error on installing JVCL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, jvcl, jedi-code-library

I have installing [**JCL**](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) via Install.bat and its successfully installed. However, when I try to install **[JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)** via install.bat, I got an error message like this:

```
[Compiling installer...]
Using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE

Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 22.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Components\JVCL347CompleteJCL241-Build4571\jv
cl\devtools\PackagesGenerator\GenerateDefines.pFatal: F1026 File not found: 'Sys
tem.Types.dcu'

Failed to compile JVCL installer

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you are not alone. [If you remove the "System." you can compile the JVCL version you have.](http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=6024)

Comment: @Lieven post that as an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparantly this is a known *(resolved?)* issue.

The solution is to [remove the "System." to compile the JVCL version you have](http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=6024)